How to make my app have access to other installed apps apk files?
I'm making an android app that shares apps and files but I have no idea how to get the apk file of other apps installed on device in my app.<br>
I know apps are installed in /data/app/package-id/base.apk
and some apps have multiple apk files I want to get those as well.
I looked into PackageManager  class and found this method that method getPackageInfo which returns PackageInfo
I found that PackageInfo has a field installLocation I was so excited because I thought it's the path of the apk file but I found that it actually an int not String <br>
How do I get the Path of apk as String from that installLocation or get the path of the apk or just the content using a better approach.

It appears that I had to dig more into PackageManager
But I could get the path of the apk file of an app and read it using this method
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo appinfo = pm.getPackageInfo("package-id", 0 );
String apk_path = appinfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir;

and you can get splits with
String[] splits_path = appinfo.applicationInfo.splitSourceDirs;

And you can just read it with FileInputStream or any other approach
I also had to add this permission
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

